# Binding DataGrid selected row in another DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a class `Book`:

```
class Book
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Title {get; set;}
 public string Authors {get; set;}
 public string Genre {get; set;}
 public virtual ICollection <Publication> Publications {get; set;}
}
```

On the form there are two (let there be `A` and `B`) DataGrids: `A` displays a list of `Book` objects, `B` displays the elements in `Publications` of selected book (ie binding to a selected line in `A`) .

The question is how to bind a `B` to the current row in the `A`?

I do so but in my opinion it's not quite correct:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BooksGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkingBooksSet, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="Auto" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Authors}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Genre}" Width="*" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>


  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      // Second DataGrid
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=BooksGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Publications}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Publisher}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ISBN}" />
          ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>

    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

`WorkingBooksSet` is `ObservableCollection` in my ViewModel

---

So I found a solve in [this binding cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a SelectedBook property in your ViewModel and bind DataGrid A's selected item to it.

```
SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedBook}"
```

Then, set DataGrid B's ItemsSource to the publications property.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBook, Path=Publications}"
```